# Integration with the RDF module

Tags: rdf

I have a module that creates HTML output.

What are the functions made available from the RDF module that allows a module to integrate with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Themes will work with the RDF module if they use the proper attributes variables. If you are generating HTML outside of the core theming system (which seems unusual), you will need to get this information yourself.

The [RDF mapping API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--rdf--rdf.module/group/rdf/7) is quite well documented. Essentially there is a mapping between fields and RDF, so a title field could have a mapping to *dc:title*.

- [`rdf_get_namespaces()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--rdf--rdf.module/function/rdf_get_namespaces/7) will show the namespaces that need to be included in your document
- [`rdf_mapping_load()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--rdf--rdf.module/function/rdf_mapping_load/7) will show the rdf mappings for an entity type

You can then add RDFa markup to the fields as you output them.

If you are using standard theme functions, then as long as you stick to the Drupal 7 guidelines, all the RDF magic should be done for you. Specifically, make sure that you use `$attributes` `$title_attributes` and `$content_attributes`.